# Quantile/inverse function of a standard normal distribution

Tags: r

My question is a tad bit complex but it's been bugging me. My assignment asks for a variable called `normal` which is equal to the quantile inverse function:

> phi^-1 = (t-0.5)/(2000)

where `t` is from 1 to 2000.

I'm not sure how to  do this in R.

So far I have

```
t = seq(1, 2000, by=1)
normal <- rnorm((t-0.5)/(2000))
```

But I know this is completely wrong, can someone help me out?

I found that there is a `quantile()` function but I'm not sure how to use it or if it applies to the question?

the code I came up with was

```
quantile(1:2000, probs = seq(1,2000, by=1))
```

Comment: you need `qnorm()` ... see the help page at `?qnorm` (it documents `rnorm`, `pnorm`, `qnorm`, `dnorm` ...)

Comment: Actually `1-qnorm` if I understand it correctly. Sometimes called the survival function if the data situation is appropriate to that notion.

Comment: So my confusion is what do i set the mean and sd to? What would I do in qnorm to achieve (t-.05)/2000 from 1:2000?